# XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open doesn't intercept ALL HTTP requests that are shown on the chrome-dev-tools

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm using a third-party embedded code that makes some HTTP request with request header origin different from mine.

When I try to intercept the HTTP requests with XMLHttpRequest, it doesn't intercept that request. I am assuming it is because it has a different origin. However, the chrome-dev-tools does intercept it.

```
let oldXHROpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url) {
  console.log(url)
  return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

It logs all the requests that have the request header origin as my domain. However, It doesn't log any requests that are shown in the dev-tools with a request header origin other than my domain.

Comment: Please post the code of the third-party plugin that does the HTTP calls. There are many, many ways to make one these days!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it has a different origin to your page, then that can only be because it is running *on a different origin*.

Probably it is inside an `iframe` (which is probably dynamically generated by the script you are using to embed the third-party code).

The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents you intercepting the requests that are being sent between the user's browser and the third-party site for obvious security and privacy reasons.